# Cannot resolve symbol 'setAdapter' (Spinner)

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to implement MaterialBetterSpinner (https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner) in my app but I am getting 
"Cannot resolve symbol 'setAdaptor'"error.

Here is the block that handles material spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)
        findViewById(R.id.spinner);
materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/source"
    android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
    app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is "adaptor"? you mean "adapt**E**r"?

Comment: They actually have the correct spelling in the code block.

Comment: thanks @pskink for the spell check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved!

I accidentally wrote the code outside the onCreate function.

Ha Ha